# Exporting MySQL database to excel using java code

Tags: java, mysql, jexcelapi

I want to export my MySQL database to .xls or .txt format. How can I do it in java. What I want to do is that there is a button in my application on pressing which, my database export to excel file. 
Thanks.

Comment: Would a .csv file be acceptable? They can be opened in excel, but they have no formatting and do not allow workbooks with multiple tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) and generate your database to any format you want. If you are using struts2 you can use `datagrid` to export it to CSV or Excel.

You may find that it is helpful:

```
SELECT ....... INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.text' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a system call to MySQL:

```
mysql -e'SELECT * FROM table'>file.csv
```

Comment: This is not CSV. This creates tab delimited values. But you are right: this file can be imported into Excel.

Comment: @AlexR Ironically, A CSV does not have to be comma separated: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to export whole DB is using the native DB tools. Take a look on this article: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-export-data-csv/

Alternatively you can implement code using JDBC or ORM that connects to DB, reads data and writes it using any format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mysql-JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

it works perfectly for .xls file

```
package com.demo.export;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class dataExportService {
    public void getDefendants(Connection con , String db) throws Exception  { 
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Workbook readWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\CEPL\\Desktop\\test.xls") );
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Workbook writeWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet desSheet = writeWorkbook.createSheet("new sheet");

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            String query ="SELECT * FROM "+db;

            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            Row desRow1 = desSheet.createRow(0);
            for(int col=0 ;col < columnsNumber;col++) {
                Cell newpath = desRow1.createCell(col);
                newpath.setCellValue(rsmd.getColumnLabel(col+1));
            }
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Row number" + rs.getRow() );
                Row desRow = desSheet.createRow(rs.getRow());
                for(int col=0 ;col < columnsNumber;col++) {
                    Cell newpath = desRow.createCell(col);
                    newpath.setCellValue(rs.getString(col+1));  
                }
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\CEPL\\Desktop\\test.xls");
                writeWorkbook.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to get data from database");
        }
    }

}
```